# como puedo cambiar la longitud de decripcion varchar de (30) a (70) en sql

Tags: sql-server

```
create table catalogo 
(nodecuenta varchar (12) primary key, 
descripcion varchar (40)  not null)
```

Answer (score 3):

De la siguiente manera:

No olvides siempre hacer mencionar a la tabla y al campo a modificar:

```
ALTER TABLE catalogo MODIFY COLUMN descripcion VARCHAR(70);
```

Comment: +1 ¡Best answer!  [La doc dice esto](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/alter-table.html): ***`MODIFY`**: More convenient than `CHANGE` to change a column definition without renaming it.* O sea, si no vas a renombrar la columna, es más conveniente usar `MODIFY` que usar `CHANGE`.

Comment: no me deja hacerlo con eso hermano, me aparece que un error de sintaxis esta cerca de modify

Comment: @AngelRodriguezAguirre el error de sintaxis te aparece porque está mal escrita la sentencia sql, podrias escribir tu sentencia aqui?

Answer (score 0):

Intenta este código

```
ALTER TABLE catalogo
CHANGE COLUMN descripcion
descripcion VARCHAR(70) NOT NULL;
```